# Javascript base64 convertion

Tags: javascript, filereader

my aswer i believe is easy. I need create a code to get base64 content in FileReader function to send to database. I try to put the base64 string and put in form type hidden but i cant do. I upload the source code bellow:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/41ynj4gc/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
    //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
    var files = evt.target.files; 

    if (files) {
        for (var i=0, f; f=files[i]; i++) {
              var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = (function(f) {
                return function(e) {
                    var contents = e.target.result;
                    alert( 
                          "name: " + f.name + "n"
                          + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n"))
                    ); 
                    document.write(f.name);
                };
            })(f);

            r.readAsText(f);
        }   
    } else {
          alert("Failed to load files"); 
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readMultipleFiles, false);
</script>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/41ynj4gc/

Answer (score 0):

Try using the function from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding) which should also support unicode:

```
function readMultipleFiles(evt) {
    //Retrieve all the files from the FileList object
    var files = evt.target.files; 

    if (files) {
        for (var i=0, f; f=files[i]; i++) {
              var r = new FileReader();
              r.onload = (function(f) {
                return function(e) {
                    var contents = e.target.result;
                    alert( 
                          "name: " + f.name + "n"
                          + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n"))
                    ); 
                    document.getElementById('b64').innerHTML = b64EncodeUnicode(contents);
                };
            })(f);

            r.readAsText(f);
        }   
    } else {
          alert("Failed to load files"); 
    }
}

document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change',
                                          readMultipleFiles, false);
function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, 
              function(match, p1) {
                  return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
              }));
}
```

Notes:

- I tested the above using an ascii file and https://www.base64encode.org/
- Removed the `document.write`. Instead the result is displayed in a `span` with id="b64" (`document.getElementById('b64').innerHTML = ...`)
- As is, will work only for 1 file. Requires minor editing or putting back the `document.write` to support multiple files

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g6g1a51p/4/